# DropDownListFor not displaying all users that are grabbed form linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some MVC code that I am trying to grab a list of users with linq, and use Html.DropDownListFor() to display them. I have debugged my code and my linq returns 8 users (which it should) however when I run the page and click the drop down, only "All" is displayed as an option.

Did I miss something?

Controller:

```
var distinctExecutedByUsers = db.validation_results
      .Where(c => c.id_merchant == CurrentCasinoID)
      .Select(u => u.executed_by)
      .Distinct()
      .ToList();
foreach (var user in distinctExecutedByUsers)
{
    vm.ExecutedByUsers.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = user, Value = user
    });
}
```

Model:

```
public PVReportViewModel()
{
    PVReportPostData = new PVReportPostData();
    Results =  new List<PVReportResult>();

    ExecutedByUsers = new List<SelectListItem>{};
}

public List<SelectListItem> ExecutedByUsers { get; set; }
```

View:

```
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
       <text>Executed By User</text><!--Need to add ExecutedBy to model-->
       @Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.PVReportPostData.ExecutedBy, 
                Model.ExecutedByUsers, "All", new { Class = "form-control" })
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks legit. Just to be sure, you're passing your built-up viewmodel instance (`vm`) to the view, right?

Comment: @StuartLC Yes I am, It is working for other things in the view, just not this one. :/

Answer (score 0):

Drop down list is blank because the controller function is not ran until after the button click, and thus the data from the linq query isn't loaded until the query is already ran.

To fix this, I simply moved this outside of the function.